# How to add a haze/dim to the photo in lightroom

Tags: lightroom, haze

I've noticed a lot of lightroom presets that adds this kind of haze/dim/noise to the photo, but when I try to add it myself I just cannot find a way to create that effect. It's some kind of a haze that can be evenly distributed accross entire photo, and can be in different colors. I'll share some examples.

So I have two questions, is there a term for this effect and how do I achieve it in lightroom.

Original:
[image]

Variation 1:
[image]

Variation 2:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The effect you are referring to is caused by raising the black point of the tone curve.

This is often used by presets in conjunction with split toning to give the black areas a slight colour tint.

Using a different tool to demonstrate:
[image: Black point adjustment]

This achieves the "hazy" look you mention. Applying split toning, without any further adjustment, the first variation can be recreated.
[image]

Comment: Yeah - that first one really is just lifted blacks & a bit of a green push, it doesn't even actually need split toning. 2 sliders, done. I was looking at a more complex solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks also to @Tetsujin, your answer was also very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The haze can easily be added using the Texture, Clarity & Dehaze sliders.
This is pushing them all hard left fairly indiscriminately…
You can affect the amount of gross or fine detail that comes through the haze by balancing the sliders.

[image]

You can throw subtle or not-so-subtle colour variation in using split-toning, which can adjust light & dark areas of the image in different directions.
Again rather randomly…

[image]

Slider settings from Photoshop Camera RAW module, Lightroom should have the same adjustments.

[image]

Or instead by just pushing saturation levels and overal tonal balence.
Again not particularly subtle…

[image]

[image]

Comment: The texture, clarity and dehaze sliders all affect local contrast of the image. To me it looks like the example images from the question only use a uniform global contrast adjustment.